# MIPS ASSEMBLY, printing out values, sudden breaks

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips

I have to make a program where I input 3 decimal values, and it returns floats of those decimal values. It then is supposed to compute and print the max for the first two values, and print out the sum and product of all the inputted values. I have the sum and the product working. I just got the max to work, but it will not print out the sum and products after the max is computed. I might be overlooking something that maybe very obvious, but I can't figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
    .data

sum:    .word   0
max:    .word   0
prod:   .word   0
bias:   .word   127
prompt: .asciiz "Enter 3 Floating Point Numbers on separate lines: \n"
bues:   .asciiz "Biased and Unbiased exponents and significand: \n"
msp:    .asciiz "Max, Sum, and Product: \n"
crlf:   .asciiz "\n"        #For printing a lf

    .macro out_str($arg1)
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, $arg1
    syscall
    .end_macro

    .text
    .globl   main       #System 'calls' main
main:   
    ############################# PART 1 #############################
    #ENTER 3 FLOATING POINT NUMBERS ON SEPARATE LINES

    out_str(prompt)     #Print the user prompt

    #Get first number
    li  $v0, 6      #Read FP into $f0
    syscall         #Do the read
    mov.s   $f12, $f0   #Copy $f0 to $f12 for printing
    mov.s   $f1, $f0    #Copy $f0 to $f1 for calculating

    li  $v0, 2      #Print FP from $f12
    syscall         #Do the print

    out_str(crlf)       #Print cr and lf

    #Get second number

    li  $v0, 6      #Read FP into $f0
    syscall         #Do the read

    mov.s   $f12, $f0   #Copy $f0 to $f12 for printing
    mov.s   $f2, $f0    #Copy $f0 to $f2 for calculating

    li  $v0, 2      #Print FP from $f12
    syscall         #Do the print

    out_str(crlf)       #Print string

    #Get third number

    li  $v0, 6      #Read FP into $f0
    syscall         #Do the read

    mov.s   $f12, $f0   #Copy $f0 to $f12 for printing
    mov.s   $f3, $f0    #Copy $f0 to $f2 for calculating

    li  $v0, 2      #Print FP from $f12
    syscall         #Do the print

    out_str(crlf)       #Print string   

    ############################# PART 2 #############################
    #Calculate the MAX, SUM, PRODUCT.

    out_str(msp)        #Print the Max, Sum, Product line

    ### MAX ###

    c.eq.s  $f1,$f2
    bc1t    printequal

    c.lt.s  $f1,$f2          # is f1 < f2?
    bc1t    print2

    c.lt.s  $f2,$f1          # is f2 < f1?
    bc1t    print1  

    ### SUM ###

    jal a3fp        #Calculate the sum
    s.s     $f4, sum    #Store the sum into memory

    mov.s   $f12, $f4   #Get the sum in $f12 for printing
    li  $v0, 2      #Print sum
    syscall

    out_str(crlf)       #Print string

    ### PRODUCT ###
    jal m3fp        #Calculate the product
    s.s $f5, prod   #Store the product into memory

    mov.s   $f12, $f5   #Put the product in $f12 for printing
    li  $v0, 2      #Print product
    syscall

    # MARS return to system.
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall

    printequal:
        mov.s   $f12, $f1
        li  $v0, 2
        syscall 
        out_str(crlf)

    print1:     
        mov.s   $f12,$f1         # print f1
        li  $v0, 2
        syscall
        out_str(crlf)

    print2:     
        mov.s   $f12,$f2         # print f2
        li  $v0, 2
        syscall
        out_str(crlf)

############ FUNCTIONS ############ 

#Add: $f1 + $f2, puts in $f4, then adds $f3 to $f4 and stores sum in $f4
a3fp:
    add.s $f4, $f1, $f2
    add.s $f4, $f4, $f3
    jr $ra          # return to caller

#multiply: $f1 * $f2, puts in $f5, then multiplies $f5 to $f3 and stores sum in $f5     
m3fp:
    mul.s $f5, $f1, $f2
    mul.s $f5, $f5, $f3
    jr $ra          # return to caller
```

I think the main problem has something to do with the c.eq.s and the c.lt.s commands to the branches.. Please let me know what you think could be the problem.

Comment: Consider this: how is the CPU supposed to know that after you jumped to `print1`/`print2`/`printequal`, you want it to jump back to where you calculate and print the sum? You haven't told it that that's what you want.